# Is the function $f(x, y)= \frac{x^3}{x³+y^2}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I want to know if the function is continuous.

$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^2},&(x,y)\neq(0,0)\\0,&(x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$

First of all, I evaluate the limit by putting the point $(0,0)$ into the function:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^2}$$
?

The result is 0/0.

Then, I used the path rule.

The first path: $y=x$

The result is $0$.

The second path is $y=x^2$. The result is $1$.

The third path is $y=0$. The result is $1$.

Are my result correct? The book says that this limit exists.

Comment: I think the book is wrong here ;)

Comment: It is not continous because of the limit, right? So, the limit doesn't exists. Correct?

Comment: Correct.  Looks like you got it!

Comment: I think the problem is underspecified. Obviously it's path dependent, so you need to specify $x$ and $y$ parametrically, say $x(t),y(t)$, then you can use L'Hôpital's rule and determine if it's continuous.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use L'Hôpital's rule to determine a suitable path.

Comment: "The result is $0/0$" No, the result is $0.$

Comment: What is the value of $f(-1,1)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof with the paths $y=x^2$ and $y=x$ is correct and shows that the limit at the point $(0,0)$ does not exist.

There is also another way to prove this and it is quite useful for someone to keep in mind.

Take $$x=r\cos{\theta}$$ $$y=r\sin{\theta}$$

We have that $\lim_{(x,y) \longrightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^3}{x^3+y^2}=\lim_{r \longrightarrow 0} \frac{r^3cos^3 \theta}{r^3cos^3 \theta+r^2 sin^2 \theta}=\lim_{r \longrightarrow0}\frac{rcos^3 \theta}{rcos^3 \theta+sin^2 \theta}$

This last  limit, in order to exist,  must be independent of $\theta$.

In a first glance someone might say that when $r$ approaches $0$ the limit is $0$,but if you notice this limit is not independent of the values of $\theta, \forall \theta \in [0,2\pi]$(we can let $\theta$ take values in all the real line but it suffices to use the interval $[0,2\pi]$ because $cos \theta$ and $sin \theta$ are $2 \pi-$periodic functions)   because different values of $\theta$ give different results

If you take $\theta= \pi/2$ then $\lim_{r \longrightarrow0}\frac{rcos^3 \theta}{rcos^3 \theta+sin^2 \theta}=0$, but for $\theta=\pi$ we have that

$\lim_{r \longrightarrow0}\frac{rcos^3 \theta}{rcos^3 \theta+sin^2 \theta}=1$

Thus the limit does not exist.

In general to compute a limit near a point $(a,b)$ you can put $x=a+rcos \theta$ and $y=b+rsin \theta$ and take the limit when $r$ approaches $0$.
Then we have our limit when the result is independent of $\theta$

Comment: Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: you are welcome.