# Check if this function $f(x, y) = \frac{x^2 \cdot y^3}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have to prove that this multivariable function is continouous,

I've used this restriction: $$(x, y) = (0, m\cdot x)$$

$$f(x, y) = \dfrac{x^2 \cdot y^3}{x^2+y^2}$$
this is valid if $(x, y) \neq 0$.

if $(x, y) = 0$, then $f(x, y) = 0$.

I can check if it depends on m, and if it depends on it I know that limit doesn't exist.

$$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, mx)} \frac{x^2 \cdot m^3 \cdot x^3}{x^2 + (m^2 \cdot x^2)}$$

$$\lim\limits_{(x, y) \to (0, mx)} \frac{x^2 (m^3 \cdot x)}{x^2 (1 + m^2)}$$

and I can simplify this function to: $$\dfrac{m^3 \cdot x}{1 + m^2}$$

and this function depends on $m$, but this is the wrong result.

EDIT: based on suggested answers, I've used polar coordinates and I'm in this situation: $$r^3 \cdot \left((\cos(\theta))^2 \cdot (\sin(\theta))^3)\right)$$
theta doesn't change anything because trig functions has a fixed range: "$-1\leq f(\theta) \leq 1$" and therefore they're limited functions, and because of this reason I can say this function is independent to $\theta \rightarrow $ thus the function is continuous

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2299382/is-the-function-fx-y-fracx3x³y2-continuous), where the answer uses polar coordinates.

Comment: Notice that $0 \le \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le \frac{x^2}{x^2}=1$, hence:
$0 \le \frac{x^2|y^3|}{x^2+y^2} \le |y^3|$. Can you conclude now?

Comment: @coudy how do you know when to use polar coordinates instead of other approaches? is there a standardized method in order to choose what method to use?

Comment: And [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982285/question-regarding-solving-multivariable-function-continuity-problems) also treats exactly your function.

Comment: Yes, this is standard.

Comment: That function depends on m, but your limit $x$ is tending to zero. So regardless of the value of 'm', the limit will be zero. What you need to consider is the value of the limit, not the function inside the limit. If the value itself is dependent on 'm', then the limit does not exist along that path.

But anyway, that's not the way to prove continuity, because this only proves that the function is continuous along the $y=mx$ path.

Comment: After your recent edit, I think the last link given by Dietrich Burde can now be considered as a duplicate: [Question regarding solving multivariable function continuity problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3982285/question-regarding-solving-multivariable-function-continuity-problems)

Comment: Btw there is a mistake in this edit. Replace "they're limited functions, and because of this reason I can say this function is independent to theta" by "they are bounded, and because of this reason I can find an function independent of theta which is an upper bound for $|f|$, and then apply the squeeze theorem".

Comment: Use `\cdot`, not `*` for multiplication.